# Regex flatten usage

Tags: ruby, regex, flatten

I am using regex to extract a value from a variable. The output comes in this format:

```
[["\"XXX.YYY\""]]
```

So, I use flatten & it gives me this output:

```
["\"XXX.YYY\""]
```

How can I extract only `XXX.YYY` from this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
a = [["\"XXX.YYY\""]]
puts a.flatten[0].gsub('"','')
```